# How to set active class with nav-tabs

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I'm using Bootstra 3 nav-tabs component as my primary navigation bar but I cant figure out how to set the active menu based on an class binding.

in side of any button for dropdown navigation to show/hide next menu bar, but the active class doesn't run

can you help me?

**Expected**: menu can show tab is active, when click button dropdown active tab is active click button

Here what I've been trying:

```
<li :class="{ active : active_el == 1 }" data-wow-delay="0.14s">
  <a @click="activateProfile" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">profile</a>
</li>
...
activateProfile() {
  this.initTabsState()
  this.isProfile = true
  this.isTabMore = false
}
```

and here my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dede402/x62p6xwm/

Answer (score 1):

The problem in in your `activateProfile()` function you have to set `active_el = 1` for profile and vice versa. Everything is working fine. you need to modify your `activate...()` functions as such:

```
activateProfile() {
  // you need to instantiate the `active_el` as well for it to work.
  this.active_el = 1 
  this.initTabsState()
  this.isProfile = true
  this.isTabMore = false
}
```

heres a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dbq59xx/) of the working example.

Comment: No Problem!! :)